# Spring - RESTful authentication using cookies

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security, spring-boot

I try to implement authentication (for my android client app) using cookies, based on this article -http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/securing-your-mobile-api-spring-security.html

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final static String TOKEN_STRING = "my_token";
    private final static String COOKIE_STRING = "my_cookie";

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userSvc;
    @Autowired
    private MyTokenBasedRememberMeService tokenSvc;
    @Autowired
    private RememberMeAuthenticationProvider rememberMeProvider;
    @Autowired 
    private MyAuthSuccessHandler authSuccess;
    @Autowired
    private MyAuthFailureHandler authFailure;
    @Autowired
    private MyLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccess;


    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userSvc)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        auth.authenticationProvider(rememberMeProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin()
               .loginPage("/")
               .loginProcessingUrl("/loginendpoint")
               .successHandler(authSuccess)
               .failureHandler(authFailure).and()
            .logout()                           
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccess(logoutSuccess)
                .deleteCookies(COOKIE_STRING).and()
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(tokenSvc).and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(rememberMeAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public RememberMeAuthenticationFilter rememberMeAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        return new RememberMeAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), tokenBasedRememberMeService());
    }

    @Bean
    public RememberMeAuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new RememberMeAuthenticationProvider(TOKEN_STRING);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyTokenBasedRememberMeService tokenBasedRememberMeService() {
        MyTokenBasedRememberMeService service = new MyTokenBasedRememberMeService(TOKEN_STRING,
                userSvc);
        service.setAlwaysRemember(true);
        service.setCookieName(COOKIE_STRING);
        return service;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

}
```

MyTokenBasedRememberMeService:

```
public class MyTokenBasedRememberMeService extends TokenBasedRememberMeServices {

    private final static String TOKEN_STRING = "my_token";

    public MyTokenBasedRememberMeService(String key, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        super(key, userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected String extractRememberMeCookie(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(TOKEN_STRING);
        if ((token == null) || (token.length() == 0)) {
            return "";
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately after a successful login my cookie is empty on the client side:

```
Set-Cookie: my_cookie=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
```

What's wrong?

**-------EDIT 1-------**

> If you login directly in the browser you get no cookie (in dev tools for example)?

I tested it using postman and I received only JSESSIONID cookie (no my_cookie).

> Also, are you using a custom login controller method? (e.g. Is your usercontroller explicitly authenticating users?)

Yes, I'm using a custom login controller method, but I'm new in spring security and if can be done without a custom controller I will be grateful for any explanations. My controller is responsible for authentication of the user.

> If you are not using spring-security to handle authentication then I suspect you may have to explicitly set cookies etc yourself

No, I'm using spring security only. At least I think so ... :)

> What is UserController login method doing?

I updated my code.

**-------EDIT 2-------**

According to @rhinds advices and the spring documentation I corrected a few things (above code is updated). Now I can login to `loginendpoint` and after login I get `my_cookie`. But I have related questions:

1. After a successful login I receive a cookie in response. To further requests I have to manually add the token (client side) if it's automatically added on the server side?
2. What about logout? How "Spring" will know which user has to be logged out?
3. What about the token expiration date? The default is 2 weeks, then what? Can I set so that the token never expires?

For people who will be do something similar I recommend a look at this great article also - https://dzone.com/articles/secure-rest-services-using :)

Comment: If you login directly in the browser you get no cookie (in dev tools for example)?

Comment: Also, are you using a custom login controller method?  (e.g. Is your usercontroller explicitly authenticating users?)  - If you are not using spring-security to handle authentication then I suspect you may have to explicitly set cookies etc yourself.  (if not, what is UserController login method doing?)

Comment: @rhinds, please see my updated post.

Comment: I have now updated my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so the best place to start is to move away from the custom spring controller for logging in and just delegate that to spring security - the docs will give you a pretty good overview of how to get started with that - [see here to get started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html)

From the linked article, if you look at the config code:

```
@Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/sign-up").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/sign-in").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/loginprocess")
            .failureUrl("/mobile/app/sign-in?loginFailure=true")
            .permitAll().and()
        .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(tokenBasedRememberMeService);
}
```

The section under the `.formLogin()` call is telling spring-security which endpoint to listen on for login attempts - e.g. if I have this config and `POST` to the endpoint `/loginprocess` then Spring-security will intercept it and use the authentication manager to process the submitted form (expecting the username and password fields etc).

The next important bit is the wiring together of your `userDetailsService` and the authentication manger:

```
 @Override protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl)
        .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
     auth.authenticationProvider(rememberMeAuthenticationProvider);
 }
```

This gives spring-security the means to attempt to load a user object given the provided login attempt - as long as you class implements `UserDetailsService` then spring security should have all it needs.

Assuming all is correct, then you should be able to remove the custom login controller method, define a `loginProcessingUrl` and then `POST` to it and spring-security should kick in and (attempt) to handle it.

It might be worth just spending some time getting spring-security config working and handling the simple login case, once that is all been delegated to spring-security machinery it should be easier to update the config to wire in the RememberMe side of things.

---

**Response to Edit 2**

I am assuming you are following the implementation details in the linked article based on the general approach here: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/securing-your-api-for-mobile-access.html  (the explanation of the implementation details that you have linked to in your op)

> 1. After a successful login I receive a cookie in response. To further requests I have to manually add the token (client side) if it's
>      automatically added on the server side?

So assuming you are logging in and then making API requests from your mobile app - as per the article, you need a webview in your app to allow users to login, once they have done that the WebView will recieve the response from the login which will include the cookie. At this point, all you care about is extracting the token from the cookie -after that, the cookie isn't needed.  In your app you can persist the token however you like, and just add that make sure you provide that in every API request you make from the app - The RememberMe implementation in the article extracts the token from the API request headers and authenticates the user.

> 2. What about logout? How "Spring" will know which user has to be logged out?

It won't - the config has set spring up to be stateless, e.g. it doesn't track logged in users, that is logged by the presence of a valid cookie (or in the case of the API requests, presence of the token we extracted) - e.g. in stateless mode, every single request made to the app is checked to see if it is authenticated

> 3. What about the token expiration date? The default is 2 weeks, then what? Can I set so that the token never expires?

Again, assuming you are following the pattern described in the link above, this does not matter, as we just use that cookie on that first login, after that your app has a remember me token that will be used for authentication so the cookie is essentially discarded from that point.

Comment: thx a lot... I changed a little my code according to yours advices. Please see my updated post.

Comment: If I will add to each request (as param/body) token, how can I get it on the server side to validate?

Comment: Your implementation of MyTokenBasedRememberMeService - where you have overriden the extractRememberMeCookie() method, Spring would normally use this to get the token from the cookie to validate the request - in this case, you are extracting the token from the HTTP header (currently called "my_token" in this example) - so spring's RememberMe functionality will take care of everything from here.

Comment: After adding `my_token` to request it works, thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you are right as regards the third question. I wrote about token, no cookie. I performed a few tests by entering different values to `setTokenValiditySeconds` method of `MyTokenBasedRememberMeService` object. After login my next requests were performed successfully (I got response code 200) but only until the token expiration date hasn't expired. After this time I got 403 error. So, with the default settings after two weeks we won't be able to authenticate our request (using old token). What do you think about this? How can I set that the token never expire?

Comment: Please reply, because I don't know what to do... Thank you in advance

Comment: Apologies, you are right - the expiry time does make a difference for remember me.  A bigger question is are you sure you want to have non-expiring rememberme tokens - other options are you maintain a similar approach as adopted so far and just refresh the token on activity (e.g. if user doesnt use app for 2 weeks then they have to login again, but assuming more frequent use just refresh the token - similar to how cookies often work now). Alternatively, if you really want to remove the expiry, look at TokenBasedRememberMeServices source that we have already overriden to get token.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.java - You will see the code that creates/reads/handles expiry stuff..

Comment: You are right, refreshing the token after expiry will be probably a better idea. I will try to do something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are receiving/sending the JSESSIONID cookie along with the requests. For example, I use [this code](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/blob/master/rest-assured/src/main/java/com/jayway/restassured/filter/session/SessionFilter.java) when using *RestAssured*.

Comment: thx, but I want to do it a little differently. As it was written in this article.